# fill a multidimensional List with the data provided by another List (Python3)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

How can I fill a List with the data provided by another List?

For example, I have a List with two entries:

```
list1=[['printer1', '172.1.1.1', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Phaser ', 'Team@Departemnt'],['printer2', '172.1.1.2', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Ricoh ', 'Team1@Departemnt1']]
```

And i want to modify some entries For example i want to split the Department entries and add two more column in the List, with a loop

```
cache= list1[0][5].split('@')
list1[0][6]= cache[0]
list1[0][7]= cache[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in an ideal format for using `pandas`:
This method doesn't use any loops, though.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['name', 'ip', 'number', 'manufacturer', 'device', 'dept'])
print(df)
       name         ip    number manufacturer         device               dept
0  printer1  172.1.1.1  12345678        Xerox  Xerox Phaser     Team@Departemnt
1  printer2  172.1.1.2  12345678        Xerox   Xerox Ricoh   Team1@Departemnt1
```

Then you can split on the `@`:

```
df['team'], df['dept'] = df['dept'].str.split('@', 1).str
print(df)
       name         ip    number manufacturer         device         dept   team
0  printer1  172.1.1.1  12345678        Xerox  Xerox Phaser    Departemnt   Team
1  printer2  172.1.1.2  12345678        Xerox   Xerox Ricoh   Departemnt1  Team1
```

If you need it back as lists you can use:

```
df.values.tolist()
[['printer1', '172.1.1.1', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Phaser ', 'Departemnt', 'Team'], 
 ['printer2', '172.1.1.2', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Ricoh ', 'Departemnt1', 'Team1']]
```

But you can easily keep manipulating the data as a table with pandas

Comment: Thanks lot that is exactly what i searching for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the lists in-place, you could use [extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
list1 = [['printer1', '172.1.1.1', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Phaser ', 'Team@Departemnt'],
         ['printer2', '172.1.1.2', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Ricoh ', 'Team1@Departemnt1']]


for l in list1:
    l.extend(l[-1].split('@'))


print(list1)
```

**Output**

```
[['printer1', '172.1.1.1', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Phaser ', 'Team@Departemnt', 'Team', 'Departemnt'], ['printer2', '172.1.1.2', '12345678', 'Xerox', 'Xerox Ricoh ', 'Team1@Departemnt1', 'Team1', 'Departemnt1']]
```

As an alternative if you want a new list, you could add the split to the list:

```
result = [l + l[-1].split('@') for l in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to get rid of the `team@dep` column in your new list, here's a one liner that will do that:

```
new_list = [l.extend(l.pop(-1).split('@')) or l for l in list1]

>>> new_list
[['printer1',
  '172.1.1.1',
  '12345678',
  'Xerox',
  'Xerox Phaser ',
  'Team',
  'Departemnt'],
 ['printer2',
  '172.1.1.2',
  '12345678',
  'Xerox',
  'Xerox Ricoh ',
  'Team1',
  'Departemnt1']]
```